# Making array to display all the results

Tags: php, mysql

Absolute newbie here. I have a simple problem:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evalucion WHERE username = '$empleado'") or die(mysql_error()); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

if ( $row['relacion'] == 'Team') {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The thing is when I do like this the array displays one less result. Is there another way to to do it?

Comment: why you're doing fetch twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evalucion WHERE username = '$empleado'") or die(mysql_error()); 

$new_arr = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) 
{
   if ( $row['relacion'] == 'Team') 
    {
      // do whatever you want;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use if inside loop

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evalucion WHERE username = '$empleado'") or die(mysql_error()); 

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) { if ( $row['relacion'] == 'Team') {
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because only one value is being checked through `if ( $row['relacion'] == 'Team')` and when this `if` condition fails, control never goes back to `while` to extract remaining data coming from `SELECT` query

To filter out all values, first, you'll need to iterate through all of them and then check for `if` condition.

to achieve this, just swap existing code as below :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) { //fetch value first
   if ( $row['relacion'] == 'Team') { //check condition
      //if condition true
   }
}//while ends
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I cannot belive how simple was it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `do while` instead of a simple `while` if you want to keep the same structure (And if you have any good reason to do so)

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
if ( $row['relacion'] == 'Team') {
  do {
    // Your code here
  }
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just alter your sql to avoid the problem all together:

```
"SELECT * FROM evalucion WHERE username = '$empleado' AND relacion = 'Team'"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to do, but you can use `mysql_data_seek()` which can reset the array pointer back to the beginning.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM evalucion WHERE username = '$empleado'") or die(mysql_error()); 

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Internal pointer has now been moved on +1 when you
// called mysql_fetch_array() above, so your next loop through
// the $result will start from the second row.
// So reset it to the beginning before the next while loop.
mysql_data_seek($result, 1);

if ($row['relacion'] == 'Team') {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        ...
```